# why dynamodb doesnt work with amplify mock?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Hello I'm starting with aws and amplify. I would like to view the mock tables that amplify mock creates but when I try to access it fails, however, appSync works fine. I'm following this tutorial and it says I should be able to access dynamodb using localhost [image]

this is the doc link https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/usage/mock/#api-mocking-setup

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked inside the `amplify/mock-data` directory?

> For DynamoDB storage, setup is automatically done when creating a GraphQL API with no action is needed on your part. Resources for the mocked data, such as the DynamoDB Local database or objects uploaded using the local S3 endpoint, inside your project under amplify/mock-data

Comment: Yes I have, it’s there but I can’t read because of its extension file, and I would like to see the tables on the browser not in a file